# How to connect existing Stripe accounts to my platform account?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created a platform account and I want to connect my other stripe accounts that I own to the platform account as connected accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to connect existing Stripe accounts to a given account you would need to do so using OAuth:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference

The idea is that you build an OAuth link using your account's `client_id`, which you can [find in the dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/applications/settings), something like:

```
https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_32D88BD1qLklliziD7gYQvctJIhWBSQ7&scope=read_write&redirect_uri=https://sub2.example.com
```

Then, you would send that link to the existing accounts you want to connect to. Once they complete the OAuth flow and grant you access to their accounts, they will be redirected to your [redirect_uri](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize-request) with an [authorization code](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize-response). To complete the connection you will need to make a request for an access token using the authorization code from the redirect as shown here:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#post-token-request

Comment: Why the access token is needed? I managed to make the connection to the platform account without this step?